# Store the first and last day of every month of the year javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I need to get the first and last day of every month of the year and set it as an array of objects. I tried the following, but got stuck and unable to get the proper results.

```
module.exports = function () {
    let months_names = ["january","february","march","april","may","june", "july","august","september","october","november","december",
  ];

  let current = new Date();
  let month = months_names.map(x => {
      return months_names.indexOf(x);
  });

  const test = {
    prev_month_first: new Date(current.getFullYear(), month[0], 1) / 1000 | 0,
    prev_month_last: new Date(current.getFullYear(), month[0], 0) / 1000 | 0   
  }

  console.log(test);


  const months = [
    {
      jan_start: "",
      jan_end: "",
    },
    {
      feb_start: "",
      feb_end: "",
    },
    {
      march_start: "",
      march_end: "",
    },
    {
      april_start: "",
      april_end: "",
    },
    {
      may_start: "",
      may_end: "",
    },
    {
      june_start: "",
      june_end: "",
    },
    {
      july_start: "",
      july_end: "",
    },
    {
      aug_start: "",
      aug_end: "",
    },
    {
      sept_start: "",
      sept_end: "",
    },
    {
      oct_start: "",
      oct_end: "",
    },
    {
      nov_start: "",
      nov_end: "",
    },
    {
      dec_start: "",
      dec_end: "",
    },
  ];

  return months;
};
```

The `console.log(test)` prints the timestamps as `{ prev_month_first: 1577817000, prev_month_last: 1577730600 }`, which equivalents to:

```
GMT: Tuesday, December 31, 2019 6:30:00 PM
Your time zone: Wednesday, January 1, 2020 12:00:00 AM GMT+05:30
```

and

```
GMT: Monday, December 30, 2019 6:30:00 PM
 Your time zone: Tuesday, December 31, 2019 12:00:00 AM GMT+05:30
```

respectively (using epoch time convertor).

I am unable to set the timestamps as per this year for each month correctly.

Please help to get me on track with this.

Comment: Would you be willing to use the moment.js library? Makes your job much easier.

Comment: @KaseyChang Yes I am willing to use one but since I am new to handling these dates using core js, I want to understand basic concepts with that first

Comment: Okay, first, you are not using the date constructor correctly. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date says the parameters are supposed to be integers if you are using year, month, and day. You are passing in a string for month. And what is that "divide by 1000" stuff?

Comment: @KaseyChang /1000 to convert into a timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could do something like this:

```
const monthNames = ["january", "february", "march", "april", "may", "june", 
"july", "august", "september", "october", "november", "december"];


const months = monthNames.map((name, i) => ({
  [`${name}_start`]: new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), i, 1),
  [`${name}_end`]: new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), i + 1, 0)
}))

console.log(months);
```

Comment: Well i don't know if this is what he is looking for but i like how you find the beginning and the end of each month. Congrats!

Comment: This is what I was exactly looking for :D. But there seems a small issue. I am getting december 2019 date in jan starting date `{ january_start: 2019-12-31T18:30:00.000Z,
    january_end: 2020-01-30T18:30:00.000Z },
  { february_start: 2020-01-31T18:30:00.000Z,
    february_end: 2020-02-28T18:30:00.000Z }...`

Comment: That's because you are in a different timezone than @Gearoid is. To compensate for this use the static method `Date.UTC()` and apply it like this: `new Date(Date.UTC(new Date().getFullYear(), i, 1))`